# Detecting mesh self intersection

Tags: python, armature

How can I detect self intersections in a mesh given a pose deformation?
I've managed to visualize them, but how can I access them?
Is there another way to detect these self intersections?

[image: blender self intersections]

Comment: Related (possible dupe) https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73869/how-to-stop-self-intersection-of-model

Comment: Thanks, but I'm only interested in detecting the self-intersections. 
I'm not looking for a way to fix or prevent them.

Comment: Interesting? Looks to me like  [Cegaton's Accepted answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/74450/15543) is all about detecting the intersections between finger and palm and finger and finger using the bones.  Can you prevent something you can't detect?

Comment: haha you are right. 
I'm looking for a more general solution right now, not just for hands.
The information seems to exist within Blender